# oracle apex 4.2 : populate a form when page is loaded

Tags: forms, oracle-apex

How can I populate the form when the page is loaded

I have tried an query base form, and a automatic fetch, but neither will display any data when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

You must create "Automated Row Fetch" process on the page. For each item on page change the "Source Type" to "Database column", and enter column name in "Source value or expression".

Comment: This is done automatically when I
Create page -> Form on a Table or view

Comment: Give more info. Try to reproduce prooblem at apex.oracle.com.

Answer (score 0):

When using the page wizard to create a query based form, the query given in the wizard is only used to define the fields on the form and create the corresponding page items. It is not used to subsequently populate data.

For that you need to add a process in a region above/before your form. Make the process PL/SQL type and provide your query there. Assuming your form is on page 2 and has fields ID and Name, use:

`select name into :P2_NAME from my_table where id = :P2_ID;`

The page or link that calls page 2 will need to set the value for P2_ID.